# MySQL data as source for PHP Graph?

Tags: php, mysql

I am trying to generate a php-graph, but not with fixed data, rather with dynamic data from mysql database. For the graph I use the code of KoolPHPSuite.

I have come pretty far, for someone with almost no experience with php coding. I only need the cherry on the cheesecake!

So to give you some context; this is my code that generates a Line-Graph.

```
    <?php 

     require "KoolControls/KoolChart/koolchart.php";

    $chart = new KoolChart("chart");
    $chart->scriptFolder="KoolControls/KoolChart";
    $chart->Width = 1000;
    $chart->Title->Text = "Patient's Progression Week#";
    $chart->PlotArea->XAxis->Title = "Days";
    $chart->PlotArea >XAxis>Set
(array("Monday","Tuesday","Wednesday","Thursday","Friday"));
    $chart->PlotArea->YAxis->Title = "Value";
    $chart->PlotArea->YAxis->Set(array("10","20","30"));
    $series = new LineSeries();
    $series-> $ds;
    $series->ArrayData(array(10, 30, 25, 50, 40)); //Here you can see they y-coordinates per day. But I fixed these myself and as you have noticed, they aren't from my database.
    $series->ArrayData(array(10, 20, 30));
    $chart->PlotArea->AddSeries($series); 
?>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>GRAPH</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <?php echo $chart->Render(); ?>
    </body>
</html>
```

So you have read my comment after the $series line about the fixed data. This code displays a respectful line graph. However, it's just the beginning of my idea.

So I began to think, "Ok, so if the format for the code is: 10, 30, 25, 50, 40 than I should write a php that 'SELECTS' the respectful data from a specific table from my database and displays the inputs just like that format, Than I should hook that output to a variable and put that variable into the place of X just like this: $series->ArrayData(array(X));

So I wrote this:

```
<?php
// Connect to MySQL
$link = mysql_connect( '', '', '');
if ( !$link ) {
  die( 'Could not connect: ' . mysql_error() );
}

// Select the data base
$db = mysql_select_db( 'WebApplication', $link );
if ( !$db ) {
  die ( 'Error: could not select database \'WebApplication\' : ' . mysql_error() );
}

// Fetch the data
$query = " SELECT heartrate FROM info;";
$result = mysql_query( $query );

// All good?
if ( !$result ) {
  // Nope
  $message  = 'Bad Query: ' . mysql_error() . "\n";
  $message .= 'Whole Query: ' . $query;
  die( $message );
}

$prefix = '';
echo "\n";
while ( $row = mysql_fetch_assoc( $result ) ) {
  echo $prefix . "\n";
  echo $row['heartrate'];
  $prefix = ",\n";}
  echo "\n";

// Close the connection
mysql_close($link);
?>
```

This generates the following:

**72.5, 64, 100, 93, 98, 84, 74, 96, 68, 57**

Which is the good format, but how do I make a variable that is hooked to the output (72.5, 64, 100, 93, 98, 84, 74, 96, 68, 57) and put that variable into the place of the X ?

I have tried some things here and there, for instance putting into the first code a line like this:

```
$source_ds = "db_connect.php";
```

and substituting that X with $source_ds

But that just runs the php code..

Thank you very much!

-M

Answer (score 1, accepted):

replace:

```
echo $row['heartrate'];
```

with:

```
$heartrate[]=$row['heartrate'];
```

This will create the array to use for the graph code

Then replace:

```
$series->ArrayData(array(10, 30, 25, 50, 40));
```

with:

```
$series->ArrayData($heartrate);
```

Uses your 'dynamic' data for the graph

To be proper if this works you should add

```
$heartrate=array();
```

above

```
while ( $row = mysql_fetch_assoc( $result ) ) {
```

Comment: Thanks Dagon, I'll try this immediately !

Comment: post any issues and i'll try and help

Comment: May God Bless you, It worked. The graph show all the right coordinates! Only thing left is, it also outputs comma's like this: , , , , , , , , , That must be from the normal format output.

Comment: Every solution, should be rewarded ;)